# Convert OpenCV Mat into a "bitmask"

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently using openCV to get a bitmask of some ascii characters.

In order to do so, i'm using the following code :

```c
// some includes might be useless in this example
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat(64, 64, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    cv::putText(tmp,
    ".", 
    cv::Point(31, 31), 
    cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
    1, 
    CV_RGB(255, 255, 255)
    );

    for (int y = 0; y < tmp.size().height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < tmp.size().width; x++) {
            uchar val = tmp.at<uchar>(y,x);
            // if (val == 0)
            //     printf(" ");
            // else
            //     printf("\e[47m \e[0m");
            printf("%d,", val);
        }
        // printf("|\n");
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (;;) {
        cv::imshow("Dot", tmp);
        if (cv::waitKey(16) >= 0)
            break;
    };

}
```

From this i would expect to see on stdout a 64*64 square filled with a lot of 0 (representing black pixel) and some 255 (representing white ones) where white pixel would form a dot.

But the resulting output is 64*64 square with only 0.

I really don't understand what i've done wrong.

Also i've tried to use `tmp.data` instead of `tmp.at` but result is the same. And when i tried to iterate from `tmp.data` to `tmp.dataend` this didn't work either (this time i had more 0 but still no 255)

Forgot to mentioned, the final aim is to store the image as an array of `uint8_t *` so if i can directly get an `uint8_t *` without going through 1000 steps i would also accept the help

Overall any help would be appreciate.
Thanks by advance

Comment: use a single channel image with `CV_8UC1` instead of `3` . => when you print it, do you see the dot? also the text might have a minimun amount of pixels to be shown and it's probably higher than 64

Comment: I there any reason to draw your point as test instead of just a "normal circle"?

Comment: @Ivan yeah the dot is just an example, i'm trying to get the bitmask of some ascii character to then get rid of opencv. Actually the putText is the only thing that make me stuck with it

Comment: When i show the image through `imshow("Dot", tmp)` the dot is shown that's why i expect to have data with values other than 0

Comment: CV_8UC1..........

Comment: makes sense, then really try a single channel, notice that you have an RGB matrix, so using `.at` returns 3 coordinates

Comment: Yeah using one channel fixed it. sorry for this stupid question. 
thanks for the help ^^

Answer (score 1):

Although the comments have pointed out that you need one channel image (CV_8UC1) instead of three channels. You or someone else may wonder why the code above doesn't work as expected.

Look into source code of [`Mat::at()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L866-L875), you will find the memory address its result is at depends on the template argument. For example, if `tmp.data` is `0x55ed6bb8d1c0`, then:

- `tmp.at<uchar>(30, 31)` is at `0x55ed6bb8e85f`, **5791** (30*64*3+31) bytes from `tmp.data`
- `tmp.at<Vec3b>(30, 31)` is at `0x55ed6bb8e89d`, **5853** (30*64*3+31*3) bytes from `tmp.data`

Your code above can never read the pixels with value `{255, 255, 255}`. That's why it output `0` only.
Use `uchar val = tmp.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0];` can make it work.